# iTunes: How do I export a podcast as an mp3 to my phone?

Tags: itunes, podcasts, android

I downloaded a free podcast, I see it in my saved episodes. I want it off of my computer and ported to my cell phone. I am new to this interface, and while I understand there are many ardent fans, I find it mostly confusing to the max. I mean, can they make the print smaller?

How? Where is it?

Do I need to set up a account and sync my devices?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an Android device

Answer (score 1):

Podcasts can be synced to your iPhone when connected to iTunes. These will then be available in the Podcasts app on your phone.

When you have your iPhone connected to iTunes view your device page in iTunes. Then click on Podcasts and from here you can manage your podcasts on your phone.

I am assuming that you are using iTunes and have an iPhone, you didnt state this in your question (although you have added these tags).

Comment: Thank you. Sorry. I should have stated that I have a Galaxy Note 3, Android, not an i-phone. Will ITunes recognize my device when connected by usb?

Comment: No, iTunes can't sync with Android devices.

Comment: Go to the podcast, right click on it and select "Show in Finder".  You should then be able to copy it to your Galaxy when it's connected as Mass Storage.  

If the format isn't an MP3, go to iTunes > Preferences, click General, and Click Import Settings.  Choose MP3 and the quality you want.  

Then go to the podcast, right click and select "Create MP3 Version."  Repeat step 1.